# Get JSON with Http status codes

Tags: java, php, json, http-status-codes

I'm migrating a project from PHP to Java.

I had no problem doing this, but the project contains a HTTP request which I couldn't set up yet. It has to grab a JSON from an API (Authorisation required) and then save it as a variable (which gets passed on to my parser class).

This is the code I've used in php:

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, null, stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => 'Accept: application/json' . "\r\n"
            . 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token . "\r\n",
            ),
            )));
```

`$url` is the request url and `$token` the authorisation for the API.

I've already tried a couple of solutions and libraries from StackOverflow, but couldn't get any of these to work in the Java Version. Also I haven't found code which includes the response code, which would actually allow the program to notify the user what went wrong.

Update: I've tried to use the libery linked in the comments, but encoding the url just doesn't work, I get a java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException:

```
String url = URLEncoder.encode(requestURL,"UTF-8");
```

I also tried:

```
Url url = URLEncoder.encode(requestURL,"UTF-8");
```

which resulted in the same error.
Documentation doesn't help to fix this. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong or give me some example code?

Comment: I'm confused, you say you're porting this stuff from PHP to Java, so why do you seem to be asking how to get the status code in the PHP?

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: check out this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/

Comment: @JonStirling I haven't implemented the response codes in the PHP version, but I want to do this in the Java Version

Comment: @WernerderChamp Then ask about that. Currently it sounds like you're asking about the PHP. The best thing would be to provide your java attempt for people to see. As it stands I think you could have gotten away without mentioning PHP at all :P

Comment: @Cristian This actually looks very promising, I will take a look at it.